# how to Communicate between react-native webView and a React web-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-webview, react-360

i'm trying to create a communication between a webView in react-native and a web-app created with React-360 (and of course React).
I'm using the react-native-webview and I follow this guide at this link to create a communication:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md
Using the example in the page, with a simple html page (like in the example in the link) with the function `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data)` in the script section it works good:

```
 <WebView
  source={{uri: this.props.link}}

    ref={( webView ) => this.webView = webView}

    onMessage={event => {
      alert(event.nativeEvent.data);
    }}
  />
```

My purpose, however, is to call in my web application inside the webView `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data)` when i click a button, for example with a function like this:

```
homeButtonClicked() {
    console.log("sei uscito, torna all'App!")
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
}
```

Unfortunately, when i click the button i got the following error:
`Cannot read property 'postMessage' of undefined`. How can i resolve this problem? Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with timeout function like in the doc

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage("Hello!")
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the solution of the problem in an old issue inside React-360 repository. React-360 code cannot access to window, so it is necessary to put the code inside a native module and from there it is possible to send a message to the react-native app.
Link to the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-360/issues/241